# Visual Studio Code: How not to show suggestions on space?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So anytime I type space it brings up suggestions, which causes problems when I type space at the end of a line (just because i like having a little space there. This way cursor is at some distance from code when i click at the end of a line, it's easier to see code, it's less cluttered), and press enter. It brings up suggestions menu and insert the first thing from there, while i just want to insert a new line character.

I also need it to show suggestions when I'm typing, but only when I type a non whitespace character, so I can't set it to not bring up suggestions on typing.

I also want to accept suggestions on enter, so I can't turn this off either.

So I'm stuck with wanting suggestions on typing, but not on space, is there a way to somehow exclude space from suggestion triggers?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize how you want to display it, this feature is called IntelliSense.

Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` (MacOs `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`)

and you can set the new key on:

```
list.toggleExpand
notification.toggle
```

if you want advance  settings, go to `keybindings.json`

more info: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't really solve the problem, those key bindings seem to be doing other things. I searched for it and i think there's no keybinding that brings intellisense based on space

Comment: Not really, we could try `Tab`, because to force IntelliSense, `Ctrl + Space` is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found a solution: turn off Suggest on Trigger Characters option.

This way it doesn't bring up IntelliSense on space or dot or anything else, but it still brings it up when i'm typing ordinary characters